# D3 - Making stroke-width covary with second data set

Tags: javascript, css, json, d3.js, csv

I'm building a pretty straightforward multi-line chart measuring values over time using a .tsv dataset. 
I want to incorporate a second .tsv that will change the stroke-width of each line. The two datasets have the same x-value(time), but one will plot each line's y-value, and the other dataset will plot the line's stroke-width (let's call it 'z') over the x and y values.

In other words: 
Dataset1 = x,y
Dataset2 = x,z

I'm using [Bostock's Multi-Series Line chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) as my base reference.

One thought I've had: Should I merge the two .tsv's into a single .json?

Comment: You'll either be parsing two TSV's or using a single JSON in two places to create your line graphs (assuming you're using data joins), so pick your battles? I find JSON to be easier with D3 just for the sheer volume of examples using JSON data vs. CSV or TSV. Then again, if the data you have access to is TSV, might make sense to eliminate conversion headaches by sticking with what you have.

Comment: Yeah, combining to a single JSON would be a pain in the A. Right now, parsing is giving me a huge headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether you're going to combine into a JSON file or a single TSV, I would highly recommend joining the two files. Apart from making data access less confusing, you'll also need only a single load call instead of two nested ones. So instead of something like

```
d3.tsv("1.tsv", function(error1, data1) {
  d3.tsv("2.tsv", function(error2, data2) {
    // ...
    something.selectAll("path")
      .data(data1).enter()
      .append("path")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d, i) { return data2[i].z; })
      .attr("d", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});
```

you could do something like

```
d3.tsv("1.tsv", function(error, data) {
    // ...
    something.selectAll("path")
      .data(data1).enter()
      .append("path")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.z; })
      .attr("d", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
```

Note that you won't be able to vary the stroke width of a line in SVG though. That is, each `path` has a width that you can't change dynamically. To achieve this, you would need to break up the line into separate segments or create a filled path that simulates a line of varying width.