# d3.js dynamically setting "stroke-width" on a path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a question very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097626/d3-making-stroke-width-covary-with-second-data-set) regarding dynamically setting the "stroke-width" attribute on a path. The solution offered was to pass the results of a function to the "stroke-width" attr for each path, which makes perfect sense but I cannot manage to get this to work.

Here is the statement that has me stumped:

```
 .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return (d.interest * 50); })
```

(The above works just fine and sets the path attr if a substitute an number like "5" for the function.)

Here is the full code:

```
<!doctype html></html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
.node circle {     
  fill: #fff;    
  stroke: steelblue;    
  stroke-width: 1.5px; 
} 
.node {    
  font: 16px sans-serif; 
} 
.link {    
  fill: none;    
  stroke: #ccc;    

}
</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var width = 800; 
var height = 500; 
var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()    
   .size([height, width-200]); 
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()    
   .projection (function(d) { return [d.y, d.x];}); 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")    
   .attr("width",width)    
   .attr("height",height)    
   .append("g")    
   .attr("transform","translate(100,0)"); 
d3.json("data.json", function(error, root){    
   var nodes = cluster.nodes(root);    
   var links = cluster.links(nodes);    
   var link = svg.selectAll(".link")       
      .data(links)       
      .enter().append("path")       
      .attr("class","link")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return (d.interest * 50); })
      .attr("d", diagonal);
   var node = svg.selectAll(".node")       
      .data(nodes)       
      .enter().append("g")       
      .attr("class","node")       
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; }) 
   node.append("circle")       
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.interest * 50 ;});    
   node.append("text")       
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return (d.interest * 50) ;})       
      .attr("dy", function(d) { return -(d.interest * 50) ;})       
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })      
      .text( function(d){ return d.name + " ("+ d.interest*100 + "%)";}); 
}); 
</script>
```

And here is sample JSON:

```
        {
  "name": "Root",
  "date": 1950,
  "interest": 1.0,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Anne",
      "date": 1970,
      "interest": 0.5,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Charles",
          "date": 1988,
          "interest": 0.25,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Frank",
              "date": 2010,
              "interest": 0.125,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Gina",
              "date": 2010,
              "interest": 0.125,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Diane",
          "date": 1995,
          "interest": 0.25,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Harley",
              "date": 2015,
              "interest": 0.25,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Ben",
      "date": 1970,
      "interest": 0.5,
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Erin",
          "date": 1970,
          "interest": 0.5,
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "Ingrid",
              "date": 1970,
              "interest": 0.16665,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Jack",
              "date": 1970,
              "interest": 0.16665,
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "name": "Kelsey",
              "date": 1970,
              "interest": 0.16665,
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `.style('stroke-width', ...)` instead?

Comment: @icanc I have tried ".attr(...)" and ".style(...)". The only difference I find is with .attr I can see the "style-width" attribute added to the <path ...> element as stroke-width="NaN" and with .style I cannot see the influence. Either way I cannot get the desired results of changing the path's stroke-width. The same function works in setting the radius attribute [as in ...node.append("circle")       
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.interest * 50 ;}); ...] for the circle node so I am still at a loss.

Comment: The `NaN` is your hint.  When you're multiplying `d.interest * 50`, the result is "Not a Number".  Possible reasons: either `d` isn't set correctly on your path, or `d.interest` isn't a valid number.  Looking at your code, it seems that `d` exists, but isn't what you think it is, and so `d.interest` doesn't exist.  `d`, for the paths, is a link object containing source and target values.  The interest values are contained in the node data objects.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Thank you for your comment; it makes sense when you explain it as you have. Do you how i could reference the values for d.interest from the nodes object in order to adjust the "stroke-width" for link objects?

Comment: The description of the node and link data objects is [available on the wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout#cluster).  If you want to use the child's `interest` value for the width of the line, you would use `d.child.interest`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to @AmeliaBR I was able to get the stroke-width to work as I desired. I changed the reference to the value from `d.interest` to `d.target.interest` as follows:

```
.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return (d.target.interest * 50); })
```

I really appreciate the guidance and help.